# Pandonic way of adding two Series with respect to bin-membership of index

Tags: python, pandas

#### Setup

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s1 = pd.Series([100, 1000, 10000], index=[0, 2, 5])
s1
0      100
2     1000
5    10000
dtype: int64
>>> s2 = pd.Series(np.arange(7)*10)
>>> s2
0     0
1    10
2    20
3    30
4    40
5    50
6    60
dtype: int32
```

Assumptions:

- The index of `s1` is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing.
- There is no index in `s2` smaller than the minimum index of `s1`.

**Clarification**: The index of `s2` cannot be assumed to have any particular order!

#### Desired result

I want to add the values of `s1` to the values of `s2` as follows (see comments for explanation):

```
>>> result
0      100 # 100 + 0, because index 0 is in [0, 2)
1      110 # 100 + 10, because index 1 is in [0, 2)
2     1020 # 1000 + 20, because index 2 is in [2, 5)
3     1030 # 1000 + 20, because index 3 is in [2, 5)
4     1040 # 1000 + 40, because index 4 is in [2, 5)
5    10050 # 10000 + 50, because index 5 is in [5, inf)
6    10060 # 10000 + 50, because index 6 is in [5, inf)
dtype: int64
```

#### Attempt

I created versions of `s1` and `s2` where the bins are the index.

```
>>> edges = [*s1.index, np.inf]
>>> s1_binned = pd.Series(s1.values, index=pd.cut(s1.index, bins=edges, right=False))
>>> s2_binned = pd.Series(s2.values, index=pd.cut(s2.index, bins=edges, right=False))
s1_binned
[0.0, 2.0)      100
[2.0, 5.0)     1000
[5.0, inf)    10000
dtype: int64
>>> s2_binned
[0.0, 2.0)     0
[0.0, 2.0)    10
[2.0, 5.0)    20
[2.0, 5.0)    30
[2.0, 5.0)    40
[5.0, inf)    50
[5.0, inf)    60
dtype: int32
```

Then I indexed into `s1` with the index of `s2` to get the values to add.

```
>>> to_add = s1_binned[s2_binned.index]
>>> to_add
[0.0, 2.0)      100
[0.0, 2.0)      100
[2.0, 5.0)     1000
[2.0, 5.0)     1000
[2.0, 5.0)     1000
[5.0, inf)    10000
[5.0, inf)    10000
dtype: int64
```

Finally I can add the values of `to_add` to `s2`.

```
>>> s2 + to_add.values
0      100
1      110
2     1020
3     1030
4     1040
5    10050
6    10060
dtype: int64
```

I have the feeling that there is a better solution, but I don't have much experience with "mapping" values to bins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your feeling was correct - there is a more pandonic way:

```
s2+s1.reindex_like(s2).fillna(method='ffill')
```

Let's break it down:

- `s1.reindex_like(s2)` returns a series whose index is like `s2`, with `NaN` where new indices were added (i.e. empty rows):
- `fillna(method='ffill')` fills each of those empty rows with the previous non-empty value

**EDITED:**
In comments, OP explained that `s2`'s index is not assumed to be sorted.
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s1 = pd.Series([100, 1000, 10000], index=[0, 2, 5])
s2 = pd.Series(np.arange(7)*10)
s2 = s2[[2,3,5,1,0,4,6]]
```

So that `s2` is

```
2    20
3    30
5    50
1    10
0     0
4    40
6    60
dtype: int64
```

Apparently, my method still works:

```
s2+s1.reindex_like(s2, method='ffill')
```

Returns

```
2     1020
3     1030
5    10050
1      110
0      100
4     1040
6    10060
dtype: int64
```

Which, if I understand correctly, is the desired output.

Comment: Combining @jezrael's answer with mine, you can make it even shorter by using `reindex_like` and passing a `method`: `s2+s1.reindex_like(s2, method='ffill')`

Comment: Does this require the index of `s2` to be montonically increasing?

Comment: Yes, it says so in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like

Comment: I'm sorry, index of `s2` does not have any particular order, just in my example.

Comment: Huh. Apparently it still works even if `s2` is not sorted. Check it out. Also, please edit your question like I've suggested, to get a non-sorted index for `s2`.

Comment: [follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62169048/why-is-reindex-likes-method-ffill-different-than-reindex-likes-fillnamet)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) with new Series created by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) with `method='ffill'`:

```
s1 = s1.sort_index()
s2 = s2.sort_index()

s = s2.add(s1.reindex(s2.index, method='ffill'))
#similar solution
#s = s2.add(s1.reindex_like(s2, method='ffill'))
print (s)
0      100
1      110
2     1020
3     1030
4     1040
5    10050
6    10060
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Does this require the index of `s2` to be montonically increasing?

Comment: I'm sorry, index of `s2` does not have any particular order, just in my example.

Comment: oops, tested `s1` for `montonically increasing`

Comment: @actual_panda - hmmm, `I'm sorry, index of s2 does not have any particular order, just in my example.` - not sure if understand, but I think best should be sorting both `s1` and `s2` before processing, mainly if used for `reindex, reindex_like`