# Why is reindex_like(s, method='ffill') different than reindex_like(s).fillna(method='ffill')

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to reindex a series with the index of another series and fill missing values.

Demo with `pandas` version 1.0.3:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s1 = pd.Series(['[0, 1)', '[1, 3)', '[3, 4)', '[4, 6)', '[6, inf)'], index=[0, 1, 3, 4, 6], dtype='string')
>>> s2 = pd.Series(['']*8, index=[6, 2, 5, 0, 4, 7, 1, 3], dtype='string')
>>>
>>> s1
0      [0, 1)
1      [1, 3)
3      [3, 4)
4      [4, 6)
6    [6, inf)
dtype: string
>>> s2
6    
2    
5    
0    
4    
7    
1    
3    
dtype: string
>>> s1.reindex_like(s2).fillna(method='ffill')
6    [6, inf)
2    [6, inf)
5    [6, inf)
0      [0, 1)
4      [4, 6)
7      [4, 6)
1      [1, 3)
3      [3, 4)
dtype: string
>>> s1.reindex_like(s2, method='ffill')
6    [6, inf)
2      [1, 3)
5      [4, 6)
0      [0, 1)
4      [4, 6)
7    [6, inf)
1      [1, 3)
3      [3, 4)
dtype: string
```

I expected the same result with both methods, why do they behave differently?

Comment: I've added code to generate your example variables. Verify that it's correct.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin thanks I made some corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option (`s1.reindex_like(s2).fillna(method='ffill')`) Does the reindexing first, leaving empty (`NaN`) values, and filling them afterwards.

The `reindex_like` returns [1]:

```
s1.reindex_like(s2)
6    [6,inf)
2        NaN
5        NaN
0      [0,1)
4      [4,6)
7        NaN
1      [1,3)
3      [3,4)
dtype: object
```

Now, you see that `fillna(method='ffill')` fills forward by the order of the series as it is sorted here (i.e. it's "forward" along the not-sorted index).

In contrast, the second option (`s1.reindex_like(s2, method='ffill')`) does the forward-filling across the sorted index. 
You can verify this claim by comparing this result (after sorting its index) with the result of sorting s2's index in the first place:

```
s_when_sort_s2_before = s1.reindex_like(s2.sort_index()).fillna(method='ffill')
s_sorted_after = s1.reindex_like(s2, method='ffill').sort_index()
pd.testing.assert_series_equal(s_when_sort_s2_before, s_sorted_after)
```

This assertion does nothing (i.e. does not raise an `AssertionError`) because the two are indeed equal.

[1] you can tell by my `dtype: object` that I'm not on the same pandas version as you, but I can reproduce the problem, so I think the solution is viable - verify it on your end.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: `s1.reindex_like(s2, method='ffill')`.  It's not clear [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for me. It has a note "Please note: this is only applicable to DataFrames/Series with a monotonically increasing/decreasing index." - but what it actually does is to fill "as if" the index was sorted.

Comment: Oh. I don't know about that, I only learned about that issue from your questions. You can raise that issue with the pandas team in GitHub. Good luck!